# Building an iOS app and watchOS app fails on AppCenter

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, xcodebuild, watchos

I added a watchOS app and extension to my existing iOS app in Xcode 11.5. After doing so, my build on AppCenter fails.

I use CocoaPods to include the AppCenter SDK in the iOS app but this is probably irrelevant.

This is the error I get:

```
error: unable to resolve product type 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension' for platform 'iphoneos' (in target 'Watch Extension' from project 'MyApp')
error: unable to resolve product type 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension' for platform 'iphoneos' (in target 'Watch Extension' from project 'MyApp')
error: unable to resolve product type 'com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp2' for platform 'iphoneos' (in target 'Watch' from project 'MyApp')
error: unable to resolve product type 'com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp2' for platform 'iphoneos' (in target 'Watch' from project 'MyApp')
```

This is the command used to archive the project by AppCenter:

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -workspace /Users/runner/runners/2.169.1/work/1/s/MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme Watch clean archive -archivePath /Users/runner/runners/2.169.1/work/1/output/build/archive/MyApp.xcarchive CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
```

I can reproduce the error locally and solve it by removing the `-sdk iphoneos` argument. However, I do not see a way to tell AppCenter to not set this parameter. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find out something, what was the issue?

Comment: No, unforrunately I didn‘t. I built newer versions manually in Xcode.

Comment: I've just run into this issue with Xcode 12.3. I'm guessing there are no workarounds?